# How to set the fetched value of dropdown to dropdown in edit module (Django)?

Tags: python, html, django

Here is the photo of dropdown where I want to fetch the data from database : - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ko15oCmKSuOiCmkFq1v0INDGgk70EzF6/view?usp=sharing

**html page : -**

```
<label>Country</label>
<select id="countryId">
   <option value="{{vr.country}}" >Select Country</option>
</select>

<label>State</label>
<select id="stateId">
   <option value="{{vr.state}}">Select State</option>
</select>

<label>City</label>
<select id="cityId">
   <option value="{{vr.city}}">Select City</option>
</select>
```

I've done this so far to fetch the records from database but i'm not geeting the values in to the dropdown list. Also, I'm geeting all the other values correctly but not getting the value in dropdown only.

So, what should I do to set default selected value in dropdown?
(if anyone wants more details please comment after this post.)

Answer (score 0):

You need `selected` attribute set on tag to make it a default option.

```
<label>Select City</label>
<select id="cityId">
   <option selected value="{{vr.city}}">{{vr.city}}</option>
   <option value="{{some_value}}">*some city*</option>
   <option value="{{some_value2}}">*some city2*</option>
   <option value="{{some_value3}}">*some city3*</option>
</select>
```

Also consider that `value` attribute is what you will receive in the body of a request and text inside `<option>` tag is the one that end-users will see.

Comment: It's still not working, I've done exact same thing as you did. But still it shows nothing. Is it because of javascript??,  because I've used script to get all the country, state, city value respectively.

Comment: @CaptionAmerica, Probably yeah, it is the problem with the data fetching, why don't you share your js code too?

Comment: Here's the link of that script : - <script src="//geodata.solutions/includes/countrystatecity.js"></script>

Comment: Then set the "selected" attribute in javascript, since you are fetching data from the script, not the template.

Comment: Exactly where i should put that selected keyword?

Comment: Selected attribute stands for it, you should set it true in your js script. So basically when you get `<option>` tag in js with selector, let's say like this: ```jQuery('#cityId').each((i, item) => {if(...some condition) {item.selected = true }}```, something like this.